How can I constrain the width of a custom input element which supports tagging?
I have the following html component which essentially adds support for tagging input values. It works as epxected except that it continues to grow passed the width of the parent container. I want it such that it epxands it's height and grow vertically. The closest I have come to fixing it is by adding the flex-wrap but that always inserts a new line in the input growing it in height even though there is plenty of room still available to the right.
The SO tags input is essentially what I want to recreate:



const input = document.querySelector('.tags > input');

input.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
    const container = input.parentNode;
  
  if (e.key === ' ' && input.value.trim().length > 0) {
    const button = document.createElement('button');
    button.innerText = input.value;
    
    container.insertBefore(button, input);
    input.value = '';
  }
});
.container {
  width: 200px;
}
.tags {
  border: 1px solid #777777;
  display: flex;  
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 0.25rem;
}

.tags > input {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-width: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.tags > button:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 0.1rem;
}
<div class="container">
  <div id="tags" class="tags">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</div>





The closest I have come to fixing it is by adding the flex-wrap but that always inserts a new line

That's because you have width: 100% on the input field.
Replace that with flex: 1 1 2em; min-width: 2em - so that it is allowed to grow and shrink as necessary, while keeping a minimum width of 2em (or use a different value, if you like.)
(Red outline added so we can clearly observe the input field's dimension, feel free to remove that again.)


const input = document.querySelector('.tags > input');

input.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
    const container = input.parentNode;
  
  if (e.key === ' ' && input.value.trim().length > 0) {
    const button = document.createElement('button');
    button.innerText = input.value;
    
    container.insertBefore(button, input);
    input.value = '';
  }
});
.container {
  width: 200px;
}
.tags {
  border: 1px solid #777777;
  display: flex;  
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.tags > input {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-width: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  flex: 1 1 2em;
  min-width: 2em;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

.tags > button:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 0.1rem;
}
<div class="container">
  <div id="tags" class="tags">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</div>



